# UglifyJS remove quotes and fails on Safari 5

Tags: javascript, safari, uglifyjs

I have this code (this code is in a javascript library)

```
var myObject = {
  'object': 'aObject'
};
```

But after use uglify-js, the code looks like this (the quotes on the property object was removed)

```
var myObject = {
    object: 'aObject'
};
```

The problem with this is that Safari 5 checks the reserved javascript words like "object, function, string, etc" and if in my object property doesn't have the property between quotes, this fails.

**Exist any option in uglifyjs for avoid this?**

Answer (score 0):

Finally i get the solution. I needed config the following option:

```
{
   output: {
       quote_keys: true
   }     

}
```